# How do I expand the range of years available in dropdown menu when using the :date datatype in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, menu, range, dropdown

I am writing a personal genealogy app with Ruby on Rails 5, and am using the :date datatype for entering birth/death dates. This results in a dropdown menu for each element (year/month/day) of a date. For the year, the menu defaults to a range of five years in the past to five years in the future (so for 2017, the range is from 2012 to 2022). But I need to have a much larger range to cover years going back multiple centuries. How can I define a specific range of years I want to be available in the dropdown menu?

Here's an excerpt from my schema.rb file (other fields deleted for brevity):

```
create_table "people", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.date "birth_date"
  t.date "death_date"
end
```

And here's and excerpt from my view file (again, other fields deleted for brevity):

```
<div class="booyah-box col-10 offset-1">

  <h1>Edit Your Person Details</h1>
  <%= simple_form_for @person do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :birth_date %>
    <%= f.input :death_date %>

    <%= f.submit 'Update', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

I should also add I need a way to have a "no choice"-type option, such as for those still living, since they wouldn't have a death date

I've searched on StackOverflow and haven't found an applicable answer, but if there's already one here, please point me to it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How did you create your current dropdown? Can you show your code?

Comment: i'm new to stackoverflow, so i'm not sure how to add code in the comments so it's nicely formatted...

Comment: Add them to the question instead; you can click on **edit** to add more information.

Comment: Also, share the code of your view, where the dropdown is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `start_year` and `end_year` in the date `input` within your view; for example:

```
<div class="booyah-box col-10 offset-1">

  <h1>Edit Your Person Details</h1>
  <%= simple_form_for @person do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :birth_date, start_year: Time.now.year - 10, end_year: Time.now.year + 10 %>
    <%= f.input :death_date, start_year: Time.now.year - 10, end_year: Time.now.year + 10, prompt: "-" %>

    <%= f.submit 'Update', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

In the example I added 10 years from current date and 10 years after current date, but you can use any range you need.

Comment: Thank you, that works. And I can set the start/end years to absolutes (like 1700) as well. Do you know of an easy way to allow the "no choice"-type option, so I can leave the death date blank?

Comment: @elbereth Yes, you can use an absolute value for either `start_year` and/or `end_year`. Also, you can add a *"no choice"* option but it will be added to all fields, that is, year, month and day; to do it just add the attribute `,  prompt: "-"`. Check updated answer for an example (i added it on `death_date`).

Comment: Notice that i used `"-"` in `prompt:`, but you can use any string you want to show as message for the blank option.

Comment: @elbereth Glad to help! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (clicking the tick on the left). Happy coding! :)

Comment: Tick clicked. I also clicked the up arrow, but since my rep isn't high enough, it didn't show.